C++ 20: trying to return std::ranges::view from a function
I am tasked with investigating performance improvement of some legacy C++ code, by leveraging CPP20. One potential area of improvement I see is this pattern in the hot path.
std::vector<engagementIndex> getEngagementsForDay(DayIndex day) {
  std::vector<engagementIndex> outputVector;
  for(EngagementIndex engagement : engagements){
    if(getDay(engagement) == day) {
      outputVector.pushback(engagement);
    }
  }
  return outputVector;
}

These are small vectors (less than 10 values typically) and the index it stores is just a short (not storing a whole object). Still this function gets called a few hundred thousand times, and I suspect that avoiding the vector memory allocation should help.
I want to replace the return type with a view instead.
Question #1: What is the return type for the appropriate view?
All the examples and discussions seem to utilize auto. At my tiny shop, auto is discouraged but if that indeed is the best option we can probably live with that.
But the bigger problem is that I can't even get my code to compile with auto.
Basically depending on some runtime conditions, I need to be able to return 4 "kinds" of views from the function.
An empty view
return std::ranges::empty_view<EngagementIndex>();

A whole vector
return engagements | std::views::all;

Part of a vector
return engagements | std::views::take(size);

Vector filtered by some condition
return engagements | std::views::filter(engagementDayFilter(day));

Each of my return statements produces a different type, preventing me from putting them in the same function.
What are my options?
I don't have any experience with CPP20, but google hasn't been too helpful.
EDIT: 10/1/24
I ended up going with an approach similar to one of the answers, but instead creating a custom single filter for each of my use cases. Effectively I am giving up on the ability to pipe filters. I am not qualified enough to say if this is better or worse, but I found it slightly easier to read.
    return engagements | std::views::filter(myFilter1(day));

But what I really wanted to share is that going from a vector copy to a view had a meaningful impact. My two target functions now are no longer on the hot path. I don't have a good way to measure the exact performance impact (our test cases don't naturally lend themselves), but I am fairly confident that the improvement is greater than 1% and less than 5%

"I suspect that avoiding the vector memory allocation should help" - make sure you profile the code to verify that. "I want to replace the return type with a view instead" - and, um, what would the view be of, if there is no vector to back it? The view can't outlive the vector.

@RemyLebeau The vector exists as a member. The existing code produces a copy of the vector (while filtering out the irrelevant elements). The master vector persists.

use std::variant, c++ doesn't have any_view yet (a type-erased view)

Is there an upper bound to the number of elements you want to return?  If so, you could put them in a std::array.

don't forget you can use std::pmr::vector and not have to heap allocate the vector.

@DrPhil "The vector exists as a member" - perhaps, but engagementsToReturn implies to me that it is returning a view into the local copy, not a view into the original member. And the local copy will go out of scope on the return, invalidating the view if it is viewing the copy.

Returning a view might be risky, they are build on iterators and can be invalidated when the content of the container (vector) changes. In other words views should only be in general be used in a local scope.

@PepijnKramer, that's a fair point. How about returning it from a private helper member function (for use by various public member functions)?

@RemyLebeau. I see what you're saying. That was imprudent variable naming on my part (it's not the actual code). I've edited my question to remove that distraction.

If you're willing to rely on the storage being a vector (or another contiguous container), std::span<const engagementIndex> might work for you, at least in three out of the four cases (unfortunate).

Make sure you are looking it the right direction. First question on performance optimization here should be "why this function has to be called a few hundred thousand times"? What is the business logic behind it? Do you really have so many days of interest or you call for the same day many times? Depending on the answer code refactoring on calling side could be done which could include caching, etc. Moving here to views and type erasure can only overcomplicate your code and make it worse.

@DrPhil That might be an option, but be sure that your class monitors the changes to the vector so it knows when to update the view.  But I think you're just adding complexity that's only worth it if the views are expensive to calculate (which they shouldn't becuase views and pipelines of views are lazily evaluated)

@PepijnKramer You bring up an important point I haven't completely thought through. These private helpers only exist to modularize the code. They're called each time a view is needed, not "stored" for later use. Multiple threads call the function simultaneously, but read only. All writing happens single threaded. Reads and writes never happen at the same time. Any pitfalls with that approach?

Yes even if a single thread writes to the vector and you have multiple readers you can have dataraces (and invalidated views). And you would need a reader/writer lock, which you can implement with a std::shared_mutex + std::shared_lock (multiple readers allowed), and std::unique_lock (one writer allowed)

So you basically want an adapter: engagementsToReturn | my_adapter(args); because a view is meant to be temporary, and the result of above must be consumed immediately, or dangling will slash you. A combination of std::views::take followed by  std::views::filter(or vice versa, for optimization) is generic enough to cover all four mentioned cases:
bool need_empty(my_arg_t);
bool filter_all(my_arg_t);
bool take_all(my_arg_t);
std::size_t get_size(my_arg_t);

auto my_adapter(my_arg_t my_arg, auto unlikely_take_all){
    auto const size
       = need_empty(my_arg)
       ? 0
       : filter_all(my_arg)
       ? ~std::size_t{} //max size_t
       : get_size(my_arg);

    auto select = [my_arg](engagementIndex const& idx){
        return take_all(my_arg)
             ? true
             : need_empty(my_arg)
             ? false
             : choose(my_arg, idx);
    };

    using namespace std::views;

    //assume take_all is :
    if constexpr(unlikely_take_all.value)
       return take(size)
            | filter(select);
    else //assume likely filter_all
       return filter(select)
            | take(size);       
};

Now you can use the adapter instead of a view:
//take_all is unlikely:
manipulate( server.engagementIndiceVec()
         | my_adapter(my_param, std::true_type);

//take_all is likely:
manipulate( server.engagementIndiceVec()
         | my_adapter(my_param, std::false_type);

Checking for empty is always possible with std::ranges::empty(my_view). But in case all elements are needed, there's always a bit of penalty for take and filter.
Once again I should state that the resultant view should be immediately used/maipulated/consumed, and not stored for later use. If it outlives the input vector, or vector size/capacity is changed while the view is alive, it will be dangling and cause UB on further use. Use views instantly.

Each one of those views can have a different size, you cannot contain them all in some type-erased object without heap allocation, which is what you need in order to return it from a function. you can use a custom allocator or pmr::vector to reduce heap allocations.
Since you want to remove heap allocations to speed up performance then your best option is to use a std::variant of them all, you can use std::declval to help you declare the variant type.
using empty_engagement_view = std::ranges::empty_view<engagementIndex>;
using all_engagement_view = decltype(std::declval<std::vector<engagementIndex>&>() | std::views::all);
using partial_view = decltype(std::declval<std::vector<engagementIndex>&>() | std::views::take(std::declval<size_t>()));
using filtered_view = decltype(std::declval<std::vector<engagementIndex>&>() | std::views::filter(engagementDayFilter{std::declval<int>()})); 

using engagement_view_variant = std::variant<
    empty_engagement_view, 
    all_engagement_view, 
    partial_view, 
    filtered_view
    >;

there is a distinction between passing an rvalue and an lvalue to the view, the above ones only store lvalues, which means the vector must stay alive unit this view is destructed.
iterating over it is a bit tricky, you need to use std::for_each, this helper struct can help.
struct engagementView
{
    engagement_view_variant var;

    template <typename Func>
    void for_each(Func&& f)
    {
        std::visit([&](auto& view){
            std::for_each(view.begin(), view.end(), f);
        }, var);
    }
};

then you can just use it
int main()
{
    std::vector<engagementIndex> indicies;
    indicies.push_back(engagementIndex{1});
    indicies.push_back(engagementIndex{2});
    indicies.push_back(engagementIndex{3});


    engagementView view{indicies | std::ranges::views::all};
    view.for_each([](const auto& t) {
        std::cout << t.id << '\n';
    });
}

full godbolt demo
the biggest disadvantages are

this doesn't compose, this only allows you to return those specific types from the function.
the vector needs to outlive the view, and the vector cannot be moved, this is only a view of the vector that exists elsewhere.
you need to list all the filters you expect if they are stateful, for stateless ones you can use a function pointer.


To solve those disadvantages you can create a type-erased wrapper that accepts any view that uses the heap or maybe a custom allocator .... which won't be much different than just returning a vector or a pmr::vector to start with.
